# play-1-3 issues in production mode?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using `play framework-1.3`. I'm having issue while running my project in production mode.

**Exception:**

```
12:21:09,282 ERROR play:602 - Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:480)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:292)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:428)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:604)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:308)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
```

I don't know exactly why i'm getting this error. I found somewhere on internet play does not support nested classes in one file. 
but i'm not doing that, than why i'm having this error ?

Comment: Can you provide more details / share some code so we can work on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play dos not support two classes in one file. that's why i'ws getting that error.

I just made 2 different classes and error gone way.

Erroe was. I was doing like as follow.

**ClassTest.java**

```
public class ClassTest {
  // some implementation
}

// in same file i declared another class.

class another {
  // some implementation

}
```

**Solution:**

**ClassTest.java**

```
public ClassTest {
 // some implementation
}
```

**another.java**

```
public class another {
 //some implementation

}
```